# React does not recognize the prop passed to a styled-component within Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

Styled-component:

```
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const Text = styled(Typography)<TextProps>`
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: ${({ textColor }) => textColor ?? textColor};
  font-size: ${({ textSize }) => (textSize ? textSize + 'px' : '16px')};
`;
```

Usage inside a component:

```
<GlobalStyled.Text textColor="green" textSize="20">test</GlobalStyled.Text>
```

"Warning: React does not recognize the `textColor` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `textcolor` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element."

Props are passed to a `Typography` component itself, not just for styled-component, how to workaround this?

**UPDATE**

Styled components released 5.1.0: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/releases/tag/v5.1.0

There's new transient props now, that solves this problem with props filtering. You can use `$propsName`, a dollar sign before your props name and it will be passed to a Styled-component ONLY!

Comment: Typo - `color: ${({ textColor }) => textColor && textColor};` or even just `color: ${({ textColor }) => textColor};`

Comment: Not a typo, FYI: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing

Comment: Thanks - but, still - what's the point of using it here? It's the same as if you would use `${({ textColor }) => textColor}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to get the props that you don't want, strip them, and pass the rest of the inside:

```
const Text = styled( ({textColor, textSize, ...rest}) => <Typography {...rest}/>)<TextProps>`
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: ${({ textColor }) => textColor ?? textColor};
  font-size: ${({ textSize }) => (textSize ? textSize + "px" : "16px")};
`;
```

Here is a working example (without the `TextProps` type, but it should work): https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-styled-component-removed-props-rfdjx?file=/src/App.js

Here is a working example using Typescript:

```
import * as React from "react";

import Typography, {TypographyProps} from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import {StylesProvider} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface TextProps extends TypographyProps {
  textColor: string,
  textSize: number
}

const TypographyWrapper = React.forwardRef<HTMLSpanElement, TextProps>(
  function TypographyWrapper({textColor, textSize, ...other}: TextProps, ref) {
    return <Typography {...other} ref={ref}/>
  }
);
const Text = styled(TypographyWrapper)<TextProps>`
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: ${({ textColor }: TextProps) => textColor ?? textColor};
  font-size: ${({ textSize }: TextProps) => (textSize ? textSize + 'px' : '16px')};
`;

export default function App() {
  return <StylesProvider injectFirst>
    <Text textColor="green">Hello World!</Text>
    <Text textColor="red" textSize={30}>Hello World!</Text>
  </StylesProvider>;
}
```

[image: Edit Remove props that are only for styled-components]

Comment: Do you know, how to correctly type the props now? I've tried `{ textColor, textSize, ...rest }: TextProps`, but it throws an error because of childs: "Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type"

Comment: @AlexanderKim I've added a Typescript example to this answer.

Comment: Thanks, i just read styled-components 5.1.0 release notes, they've implemented transient props: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/releases/tag/v5.1.0, i just used transient prop `$propsName` and it just worked!

Comment: @RyanCogswell, that looks like a too much work just to pass a custom SC props, lol, i'm glad they finally introduced these transient props.

Comment: @AlexanderKim Yes, transient props sound like a much nicer solution.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, just curious, do you use Material UI with SC on any production web-apps? This way to filter props, as you wrote above, would be cumbersome to write in every component, indeed.

Comment: @AlexanderKim No, I just use the bundled JSS solution (and I just started learning Typescript yesterday -- I don't currently use it outside of StackOverflow).

Answer (score 7):

Using "transient props" from styled component

https://styled-components.com/releases

Styled Component

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Typography, { TypographyProps } from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
    
interface TextProps {
    $textColor?: string;
    $textSize?: number;
}

export default styled(Typography)<TypographyProps & TextProps>`
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: ${(props) => props?.$textColor || 'black'};
    font-size: ${(props) => props?.$textSize ? props?.$textSize +'px' : '16px'} !important;
`;
```

Use

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Text from "./components/Text";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Text $textColor="blue" $textSize="50" align="center">
        text ok
      </Text>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-transient-styledcomponent-example-eb9uf?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```html
<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-transient-styledcomponent-example-eb9uf?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark" style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;" title="react-typescript-transient-styledcomponent-example"
  allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 6):

With [version 5.1.0](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/releases/tag/v5.1.0), styled-components supports transient props. Transient props are not passed to component (i.e. just used in the styling) and are indicated by starting the prop name with `$`. This allows for a much simpler way of managing this scenario that no longer requires a wrapper component to remove the extra props (as in Dekel's answer).

```
import * as React from "react";

import Typography, { TypographyProps } from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface TextProps extends TypographyProps {
  $textColor?: string;
  $textSize?: number;
}

const Text: React.FunctionComponent<TextProps> = styled(Typography)`
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: ${({ $textColor }: TextProps) => $textColor};
  font-size: ${({ $textSize }: TextProps) =>
    $textSize ? $textSize + "px" : "16px"};
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <Text $textColor="green">Hello World!</Text>
      <Text $textColor="red" $textSize={30}>
        Hello World!
      </Text>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Remove props that are only for styled-components]